# Can't get to airship

Tags: final-fantasy

I'm playing the Windows Phone version of FFI.

I was trying to do the optional dungeon Hellfire Chasm. I actually managed to clear it by reaching Hellfire Chasm B10 and killing the boss. The teleporter took me to the entrance of the dungeon, but now my airship isn't there. It is in the island to the north. In this Island there are just two caves, Dragon Caves B1 and Hellfire Chasm.

Is there a way to teleport to a town or to reach my airship?
I've tried:

- Entering the dungeon and using emergency exists
- Let monsters kill my party

But I m still reappearing at the wrong side. I'm fearing that I have to restart the game.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't reach  your airship by land, or with the canoe or your ship-then you will have to reload. Your ship should be close by, try using that to get you there.